# How to access a Django variable in an external JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am making a Django website. In it I am trying to access a variable in view.py file in an external static JS file linked to my template.

I tried using the syntax `var is_empty = "{{is_empty}}"`, but it didn't work in a if statement where `if(Number(is_empty) == 1)`, and also I tried creating a div in my body(with `id = "temp"`) and adding an attribute `data-dj = {{is_empty}}` and then using `var is_empty = document.getElementById("temp").getAttribute("data-dj");`, but it was showing an error that cannot call getAttribute on null.

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing django variables to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886765/passing-django-variables-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a variable within a script tag in your Django template and then access this variable in your external JavaScript.

In your Django template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVar = "{{ django_variable }}";
</script>
<script src="path/to/your/external.js"></script>
```

In your external JavaScript file (external.js):

```
console.log(myVar); // Access the Django variable
```

Or you can use data attributes in HTML elements to store Django variables and then access these attributes from your external JavaScript.

In your Django template:

```
<div id="myElement" data-myvar="{{ django_variable }}"></div>
<script src="path/to/your/external.js"></script>
```

In your external JavaScript file:

```
var myVar = document.getElementById('myElement').getAttribute('data-myvar');
console.log(myVar);
```

Comment: This ought to be obvious, but do take care when a script is passed through the Django template not to code `{{` for anything except Django substitutions. Code `{ {` where the two braces are JavaScript block delimiters. The whitespace is significant and the errors if you get this wrong are gnarly. Ditto `} }`

Answer (score 0):

If **is_empty** type is boolean then try like this:

```
if ("{{is_empty}}" === "true")
```